# How to access Swift class-level enum from Objective-C code

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm in the midst of a rewrite and I'm at the point where I'm converting my Core Data models over to Swift. One such model, `PointOfInterest` contains an `enum` called *types*, which is used to identify the type of `PointOfInterest` an object is:

```
@class Port;

@interface PointOfInterest : NSManagedObject

enum types {
    kGeneral,
    kRestaurant,
    kTypeCount
};

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * averageRating;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * city;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * countryName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * id;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * imageURL;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * latitude;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * longitude;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * phone;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * postalCode;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * priceLevel;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * rankingNumber;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * rankingString;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * state;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * street1;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * street2;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * totalReviews;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * type;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * webURL;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *ports;
@end

@interface PointOfInterest (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)addPortsObject:(Port *)value;
- (void)removePortsObject:(Port *)value;
- (void)addPorts:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removePorts:(NSSet *)values;

@end
```

In Swift, the code looks like this:

```
// PointOfInterest.swift

class PointOfInterest: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var averageRating: NSNumber
    @NSManaged var city: String
    @NSManaged var countryName: String
    @NSManaged var id: NSNumber
    @NSManaged var imageURL: String
    @NSManaged var latitude: NSNumber
    @NSManaged var longitude: NSNumber
    @NSManaged var name: String
    @NSManaged var phone: String
    @NSManaged var postalCode: String
    @NSManaged var priceLevel: String
    @NSManaged var rankingNumber: NSNumber
    @NSManaged var rankingString: String
    @NSManaged var state: String
    @NSManaged var street1: String
    @NSManaged var street2: String
    @NSManaged var totalReviews: NSNumber
    @NSManaged var type: NSNumber
    @NSManaged var webURL: String
    @NSManaged var ports: NSSet

}
```

The extension containing the `enum` is in a different file (and I renamed the `enum` values)

```
// PointOfInterest+Helpers.swift
extension PointOfInterest
{
    @objc enum Types:Int
    {
        case General
        case Restaurant
        case TypeCount
    }

}
```

In one of my original Objective-C Views, I have the following line (and a few others, but we'll concentrate on this one, as they all have the same error) which generates the error: `Semantic issue: Use of undeclared identifier 'kGeneral'`

```
poi.type = [NSNumber numberWithInt: kGeneral];
```

Even if I change `kGeneral` to `General` or even `TypesGeneral`, nothing seems to work to access this `enum` value from `PointOfInterest`. The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24139320/is-it-possible-to-use-swifts-enum-in-obj-c) doesn't help.

So my question is: how do I retrieve the value of a Swift class-level `enum` from Objective-C code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how do I retrieve the value of a Swift class-level enum from Objective-C code

You can't. Objective-C has no notion of an enum as being "inside" another class. Put the enum at top level if you want Objective-C to be able to see it.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you mean by "top level?" In still fairly new to Swift and some of the lingo is still foreign.

Comment: Don't put it inside an extension to a class. Just define it at the top level of any Swift file.