# Avoiding "Interface type cannot be statically allocated" after converting Objective-C typedef to Swift enum

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have a `typedef` definition in Objective-C like this:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, MyStatus) {
    MyStatusUnknown = -1,
    MyStatusBad = 0,
    MyStatusGood = 1
}
```

This enum is in a pod, and it's used by several downstream pods, and the app like this:

```
@property (readonly, nonatomic, assign) MyStatus myStatus;
```

**I need to convert class with `typedef` to Swift without changing the signature of enum definition in downstream pods.**

I tried a straight forward conversion first:

```
enum MyStatus: Int {
    case unknown = -1
    case bad
    case good
}
```

But in this case, the property statement above will show an error:

> Interface type cannot be statically allocated

This error can be resolved by changing property to

```
@property (readonly, nonatomic, assign) MyStatus *myStatus;
```

but as I said before, I cannot change this property definition.

So how to convert `typedef` to Swift, while maintaining its backward compatibility with existing Objective-C property?

Comment: you forgot to add `case` keyword `case unknown = -1, bad, good`

Comment: @LeoDabus yes, thanks, that's a mistake in question though, not in real code (I simplified actual enum I converted to just show a minimum here

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to use Swift's Enum in Obj-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24139320/is-it-possible-to-use-swifts-enum-in-obj-c)

Comment: @Willeke I didn't ask how to use Swift enum in Objective C, I *know* how to do that. I asked **how to preserve statically allocated property after converting Objective C typedef to Swift enum** - entirely different question.

Answer (score 0):

In your *.swift file you have to declare (`@objc` is required)

```
@objc
public enum MyStatus: Int {
    case unknown = -1
    case bad
    case good
}
```

Then autogenerated -Swift.h will contain

```
typedef SWIFT_ENUM(NSInteger, MyStatus, closed) {
  MyStatusUnknown = -1,
  MyStatusBad = 0,
  MyStatusGood = 1,
};
```

including that -Swift.h in precompiled headers (or directly if needed) will give that declaration available for Objective-C file having `myStatus` property.